# Skew-Normal Distribution when one variate is not standard normal

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I am studying about the skew-normal distribution and stumbled this [work](https://faculty.niu.edu/math_pourahm/docs/skewnorm.pdf), where a skew-normal RV has the form [Eq. (3)]:

$X = \delta |Z_1| + \sqrt{1-\delta^2} Z_2$,

where $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are independent standard normal RVs and $\delta$ is some constant.

I am really curious that what is the distribution of $X$ when $Z_1$ is not standard normal RV? Specifically, when $Z_1 \sim {\cal N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$? Is $X$ still called skew-normal?